# Проблема с запросом update

Tags: jdbc, java, sql

Здравствуйте, форумчане.

Привела меня к вам проблема с выполнением запроса UPDATE. Она заключается в следующем. Программа при выполнении запроса

```
String sqlReqest = "UPDATE "+strTableName+" SET Question='"+strQestoinText+"',FirstAnswer='"+strFirstAnswer+"',SecondAnswer='"+strSecondAnswer+"',ThirdAnswer='"+strThirdAnswer+"',FourAnswer='"+strFourthAnswer+"',TrueResolt='0110' WHERE Question='"+strRedactRecoedQestion+"'";

System.out.println(sqlReqest);
```

возвращает мне ошибку:

> `java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][Драйвер ODBC dBase] Слишком мало параметров. Требуется 3.`

Запрос в консоли выглядит так:

```
UPDATE TST7.DBF SET Question='hhh234g4t56gferthgdfd',FirstAnswer='ghfbvdsfgb',SecondAnswer='hbgvfdsfgbhnvf',ThirdAnswer='sdf ghjngbvfc',FourAnswer='dgfbhnjmkujhygtf',TrueResolt='0110' WHERE     Question='234g4t56gferthgdfd'
```

Еще один интересный момент заключается в том, что этот самый запрос вида

```
"UPDATE" + strTableName + "SET Question = '" + strQestoinText + "' where Question =         '" + strOldQuestion + "'
```

выполняется без проблем, но только я меняю количество полей в WHERE или после него, получается та же ошибка ((

Подскажите, пожалуйста, где я напортачил, где может быть ошибка?

Comment: запрос в консоли отрабатывает?

Comment: вы имеете в виду выполнял я запрос через консоль-нет

Comment: statement = connection.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);  

вместо

statement = connection.createStatement();

большой погоды не делает?

Comment: я уже писал в прошлом твоем вопросе - проверь таблицу и поле в ней.. может это поля в разных таблицах, может опечатка в названии столбца

Comment: запрос выполняю к только созданной таблице, название полей в запросе обновления копировал из запроса создания таблицы

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Это конечно скорее всего студенческая лаба, но НИКОГДА так не пишите даже дома для себя такой ужас!
Есть прекрасный PreparedStatement в котором можно сделать так:

```
PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement("update table set question = ?, FirstAnswer = ? where question = ?");
ps.setString(1, "first");
ps.setString(2, "second");
ps.setString(3, "third");
ps.execute();
```

Смысл PreparedStatement в разграничении параметров запроса от самого запроса. К примеру введите в вашем примере строку с одинарной кавычкой, результат не заставит ждать.

Comment: Молодец, брат... У меня так и не поднялась рука написать ответ на такой корявый вопрос

Answer (score 0):

я нашел проблему, она заключадась в том, что запрос на создание таблицы давал названия столбцов

Question

FirstAnswer

SecondAnswer

ThirdAnswer

FourAnswer

TrueResolt

при создании таблицы названия полей обрезались до 10 символов
и получалось

Question

FirstAnswe

SecondAnsw

ThirdAnswe

FourAnswer

TrueResolt

обновление таких обрезанных полей работает корректно, спасибо за помощь